# Is this a dependent or independent clause?

Tags: sentence-construction

Sally told her friend that because she smelled bad, she no longer wished to be friends with her.

This sentence from a previous question says the clause after the comma is dependent. Why?

Comment: Who says the clause after comma in this sentence is dependent?! "*she no longer wished to be friends with her.*" can stand alone as a sentence, so it's independent.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment from @Helen.

> Sally told her friend that because she smelled bad

This is a dependent clause, it cannot stand alone as a sentence. It must be attached to an independent clause to be included in a sentence.

> she no longer wished to be friends with her

This is an independent clause. It can stand alone as a sentence without being attached to any other clauses. However, if this was a stand-alone sentence, the sentence would have a grammatical problem as the pronoun 'her' does not have an antecedent noun. In fact, the full sentence:

> Sally told her friend that because she smelled bad, she no longer wished to be friends with her.

also contains a grammatical error. In this sentence, the first time the pronoun 'she' is used the antecedent is 'friend', but the second time it is used the antecedent is 'Sally'.  Similarly,  the first time the pronoun 'her' is used the antecedent is 'Sally', but the second time it is used the antecedent is 'friend'. The second problem (i.e., with the use of 'her) is not as serious as it is used as a possessive pronoun the first time and as a personal pronoun the second.

This ambiguity could temporarily lead the reader astray, causing this sentence to be understood as saying:

> Sally told her (i.e., Sally's) friend that because she (i.e., her friend) smelled bad, she (i.e., her friend) no longer wished to be friends with her (i.e., Sally).

This misunderstanding would not last long; the internal logic of the sentence would cause the reader to quickly interpret the sentence correctly. However, one of the first rules of communication is to make your communications as easy to understand as possible, so ambiguity should be avoided.

As a general rule, the same personal pronoun should not be used to refer to two different antecedents, unless it is used in a different clause in which the new antecedent appears as the nearest noun before the personal pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

A **dependent clause** is a group of words containing a subject and a verb (or a verb phrase), but it does not express a complete thought, so it can't stand alone as a sentence.

An adverbial clause is a dependent clause that usually answers one of these questions:

- Why?
- When?
- Where?
- How?

*(Since your sentence is ambiguous (I don't know whether "she" refers to Sally or her friend), let's assume she is talking about her male friend.)*

In your sentence, "because he smelled bad" is **an adverbial clause** and "she no longer wished to be friends with him" is **the main clause.**

If you use the adverbial clause before the main clause, you should place a comma between it and the main clause (as in your sentence).

But if your adverbial clause follows main clause, you won't need a comma.

> Sally told her friend that she no longer wished to be friends with him because he smelled bad.